# find in mongoose returns nothing when there is a non existing field in the schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a mongoose Schema like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CitizenSchema = new Schema({
  SSN: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
});

const Citizen = mongoose.model('Citizen', CitizenSchema);

module.exports = Citizen;
```

and I have a route in my express app that is like this:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  if (Object.keys(req.query).length === 0) {
    // Get all the citizens if there is no query
    Citizen.find({})
      .select('-SSN')
      .then((citizens) => res.send(citizens));
  } else {
    const query = req.query;

    // Add case insensitive to all queries
    for (const q in query) {
      query[q] = {
        $regex: new RegExp(query[q], 'i')
      };
    }

    Citizen.find(query)
      .select('-SSN')
      .then((citizens) => res.send(citizens))
      .catch((err) => res.status(400).send({ msg: 'Bad query request' }));
  }
});
```

So what I do is that if there is not a query, I return all the citizens and if there is a query, I return the query result.
For example if I send a http request to my route with a GET request like  `http://localhost:5000/api/citizens/`, I get all the citizens. And if I send it with a query like `http://localhost:5000/api/citizens/?lastName=Doe&firstName=john`, I only get the citizens with the first name as John and last name as Doe.
So my problem is that if I try and do a request like `http://localhost:5000/api/citizens/?lastName=Doe&q=test`, I get an empty array and not the citizens that have Doe as their last name. The query `q` makes it so that the `Citizen.find()` does not work properly and does not return the result that I am waiting for.
I will be appreciate it if someone could help me fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `$or` in your queries: https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/or-in-mongoose-1018